# Oracle SQL Special Period Format

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a special fiscal period in format YYYYMMM, for example

Feb of 2015 is 2015002

Nov of 2014 is 2014011

I need to do subtraction from the period, 2 months ago from 2015002 is 2014012, but i cant do like

```
SELECT '2015001' - 2 FROM DUAL
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 4):

You should first convert it to a date, then subtract months and convert back to the format you need.

```
with x(y) as (
  select '2015002' from dual
)
select y,
       to_date(y,'YYYY"0"MM'),
       add_months(to_date(y,'YYYY"0"MM'),-2),
       to_char(add_months(to_date(y,'YYYY"0"MM'),-2),'YYYY"0"MM')
 from x
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/5208/0)**:

```
|       Y |     TO_DATE(Y,'YYYY"0"MM') | ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(Y,'YYYY"0"MM'),-2) | TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(Y,'YYYY"0"MM'),-2),'YYYY"0"MM') |
|---------|----------------------------|---------------------------------------|------------------------------------------------------------|
| 2015002 | February, 01 2015 00:00:00 |            December, 01 2014 00:00:00 |                                                    2014012 |
```